# Stop table view from bouncing when presenting view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout

I currently have a view controller that has a segmented control and a table view as subviews of its view. The following view controller is always displayed within a navigation controller (including its toolbar) and it’s subviews are laid out as follows:

Segmented control: Top, leading and trailing constraints are pinned to the superview with constant values of 0.

Table view: Bottom, leading and trailing constraints are pinned to the superview with constant values of 0.

The segmented controls bottom to the table views top have a constant value of 8.

The view is resized and works without any issues when displayed within a navigation controller. I can scroll both up and down and all cells are visible.

The current problem I have is when I have scrolled down to the last cell and I want to present another view controller using the presentViewController:animated:completion: method. The issue is the whole table view bounces up, hits the segmented control and scrolls up 1 cell to the second last cell automatically. This is a behaviour I do not want as I don’t want the user to have to scroll down to the last cell again. This happens even if only part of the last cell is visible. There is no bouncing when I present the view controller when the last cell is scrolled out of view.

So far I’ve tried turning off all bounces and it still doesn’t stop this behaviour.

Any ideas on what’s causing this and how I could stop it from happening? I’ve been stuck on this for the past 3 days.

Comment: "using the displayViewController:animated: method" Can you explain what the `displayViewController:animated:` method is?

Comment: Matt - Sorry it was a typo. It's the presentViewController:animated:completion method. I've edited the original post for accuracy. I'm presenting another view controller and it's presentation is animated.

Comment: Fine, but we have no info except what you say. If you are not accurate, it is impossible to assist.

Comment: So, have you any `viewWillDisappear:` code? What kind of view controller is this? (Is it a table view controller?) Just casting about for possible causes...

Comment: [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES];

Comment: I then call the super implementation.

Comment: It's a subclass of UIViewController. It has a table view as a subview of its view.

Comment: Wild idea: if you don't hide the toolbar like that, does the problem go away?

Comment: Thanks Matt. That worked. What was I thinking! I was trying to hide the toolbar as the view controller was being presented.

Comment: Notice the logic I used. My reasoning was: something odd is happening; that means _you_ are doing something odd. Where might you be doing that? Well, it's happening as you leave this v.c. to present another; that sounds like `viewWillDisappear:`. Finally, when in doubt, comment out some code and see if the problem goes away; if it does, that was it. :)

Comment: It makes perfect sense :)